# How much free storage should I keep?

Tags: internal-storage

I have a Huwaei mate 10 lite and it has internal 64 GB, I don't use memory card because I use two sims.

How much free storage should I keep? Is 10% enough? Or 20%?

Answer (score 0):

Use as much as you need – but keep free as much as possible:

- At about 10% you'll start to receive [warnings about storage space running low](/tags/insufficient-memory/info), so you shouldn't go below that.
- Plus, the more free space is available, the better the controller can handle [wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) – which will prolong the life-span of your storage.